# How to redirect site with Javascript

Tags: javascript

> hi everyone, this is my site taxitube.io, but problem is than when I
>   write www.taxitube.io, the site not opening, can someone help how to
>   resolve this problem...

Comment: Please read the FAQ about how to post questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: After visiting [http://www.taxitube.io/](http://www.taxitube.io/), it doesn't look it's a real domain of any kind. taxitube.io and www.taxitube.io are two different domains and if you want both of them, you're going to have to buy both of them separately.

Comment: @NobleMushtak no it is a single domain with sub-domains. if he have taxitube.io and configured the DNS properly, he will be fine

Comment: @litelite Oh...Then perhaps he has the wrong DNS configuration? I don't know much about DNS, but all that I'm noticing is that http://taxitube.io is a real Web site while [www.taxitube.io](http://www.taxitube.io/) gives my Chrome browser a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error which usually happens to me when I mistype a URL and the result is that I tried to visit a Web site that wasn't in the DNS server.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *most probably* in your DNS setting. You will need to create a sub-domain for www. that redirects to your domain (without the www.). Ask your domain name registrar on how to do that.

Also Please note that such change might take a While (maybe a day) to be applied

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = " www.taxitube.io"
</script>
```

you means this you need to redirect your page to a definitely website?!

Comment: I need "www.taxitube.io", this domain, redirect to this "taxitube.io"

Comment: Thats the correct way to do that in JS. but i think his problem is deeper than that.

Comment: i think it is a config problem ,not control by js.Would you pls check this webisite and confirm is it a good way to answer your question link:https://www.chriswiegman.com/2011/09/how-to-properly-redirect-your-domain-with-or-without-www/